# Converting from latin1 to utf8mb4 of ENUM and SET with accented characters on mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, utf-8, data-conversion

I am trying to convert tables from latin1 to utf8mb4 on MySQL 5.7.

Everything works fine except the tables with ENUM and SET which contains a value with an accented character. 2 types of errors are generated.

For exemple:

```
CREATE TABLE `car` (
  ...
  `color` enum('Rouge','Bleu foncé',...) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This query does not work:

```
> ALTER TABLE `car` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

#1265 - Data truncated for column 'color' at row 4
```

On other tables I get this error:

```
#1291 - Column 'origin' has duplicated value 'Cor?e' in ENUM
```

Global and session variables are:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

PS: Current work around is to:

1. convert `enums`/`sets` to `varchars`
2. convert table charset
3. convert back `varchars` to `enums`/`sets`

Comment: The string value of ENUM datatype column is not a column value but a column definition.  Real column value (the value which is stored in the table body) is TINYINT. So charset/collation specifying for the value makes no sense. Check for `character_set_results` value.

Comment: `character_set_results` is `utf8mb4`

Answer (score 1):

The charset for ENUM/SET *may* be set

- on `CREATE DATABASE`
- or `CREATE TABLE`
- Or during the connection parameters  (Cf `SET NAMES`)  together with the setting of the app that is talking to MySQL.

I don't know which.

(The DBFIDDLE proposed fails to play with DATABASE or the connection, so it may be working without understanding why.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying change the whole table, try changing just the column and

First make an empty table and change the definition of the color column

```
CREATE TABLE car_copy LIKE car;
ALTER TABLE car_copy
    MODIFY COLUMN color enum('Rouge','Bleu foncé',...) 
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
;
```

If this works, you can attempt or inserting data into car_copy

```
INSERT INTO car_copy SELECT * FROM car;
```

or just do the ALTER TABLE on car

```
ALTER TABLE car
    MODIFY COLUMN color enum('Rouge','Bleu foncé',...) 
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
;
```

Please try these and tell us what happens

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error doing the conversion on the table or column level. May it be an old bug? https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=21524

Comment: This answer should work (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/moDrXxEj)).    Please specify the COMPLETE definition from your ENUM, because `'Cor?e'` does not seem to exist in the given example....

Comment: @Luuk Thanks!!! Actually it is an other table to replicate issue: "Bleu foncé", "Bleu foncé moyen". Seems like meta data is stored in ISO and does not properly convert. Maybe there is a configuration issue I have to investigate.